# problems with ubuntu usb installation

Tags: ubuntu, usb, installation, operating-systems

I install ubuntu using my usb drive. After the installation, everything goes great. However, I need to Keep plug-in my usb in order to use ubuntu. When I remove my usb, the ubuntu system get freeze. I cannot open any file nor open web-browser.

How can I remove the usb after the installation of ubuntu in order to work?

Comment: More information on the install procedure you used should make it a bit clearer what may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

**Boot from the hard disk.**

As the message after installation says, you can either *continue testing Ubuntu* (from USB) or *boot to your new system* (from hard disk). It doesn't automagically switch to hard disk instance after installation.

Once Ubuntu is installed, you can simply boot to it, just like with any other operating system. If your computer uses UEFI (if it's post-2011 then it probably does) and you have previously used another operating system like Windows, you may have to manually select Ubuntu for booting each time (probably by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> at the first screen after powering PC on). You can also reconfigure UEFI to boot into Ubuntu by default.

If your computer is using the old BIOS or you have CSM enabled in UEFI, then Ubuntu will configure a boot manager that will let you select OS each time automatically.

So install Ubuntu, then restart your PC. It will ask you to remove installation media (USB). It will then proceed to boot again, which will give you the opportunity to choose which OS to load.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GRUB got installed on the USB drive instead of on the internal hard drive. The device name of the internal hard drive is something like `/dev/sda` , you can check it from Ubuntu using the Disks application.

To repair the GRUB bootloader open the terminal and type:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda # replace /dev/sda with the device name you found in Disks   
sudo reboot
```

These commands will install GRUB to the MBR of the internal hard drive and make it bootable.